# Attach Sphinx PDF output to Sphinx HTML output

Tags: python, python-sphinx

This is a really weird question:

I have been able to generate html and pdf output using Sphinx; and I had to bundle both with my [distribution (to PyPI)](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3aaction=display&name=Pyvolution&version=1.0.1) so that both would be accessible to the user.

Though I can upload HTML documentation directly to be hosted on PyPI, I am unable to upload the PDF LaTeX version of it as well. I want to do this because the actual code is under 50K, but bundling the documentation with it bloats it up to about 300K.

Ultimately, I would like the user to be able to have an off-line version of the documentation without having to download several pages of sphinx documentation.

So my question is this: is it possible for me to automatically bundle the PDF with the HTML so that an end user can directly download the PDF for off-line use? (I realize that I can bundle just the PDF with my distribution, but this seems a cleaner approach)

Comment: I don't think so. If you can host the PDF file somewhere (like DropBox), you can include a download link to it in the HTML. Another alternative would be to compress the PDF file -- depending on its contents, it may shrink considerably.

Comment: Compressing the PDF did cross my mind. But as a design decision, the docs should really not be bundled with the distro. That's what I'm aiming for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went with a modification of Reinout van Rees's solution:

I created a `downloadMe.rst` (which has lorem ipsum text within it) which gets automatically built into HTML when `make html` is run and therefore makes `downloadMe.html` with the lorem ipsum text.

I then edited the Makefile's html target as follows:

1. make it build the LaTeX pdf and copy it over into `_build/html/static`.
2. use a `sed` script to replace the lorem ipsum text in `downloadMe.html` with an HTML hyperlink to the PDF in `_build/html/_static`.

When all of that was done, this is what the html target in `Makefile` looks like:

```
html:
        @echo "Making LaTeX"
        make latex
        ( cd _build/latex/; make ) # the LaTeX needs to be built separately. This can be done in a subshell
        @echo "Done making LaTeX"
        @echo "Copying PDF to Static"
        cp _build/latex/Genetic.pdf _build/html/_static/
        @echo "Copy PDF to Static... DONE"
        @echo "Adding PDF to HTML"
        sed -i '' 's/lorem\ ipsum/\<a href="_static\/Genetic.pdf"\>Download\ Me\<\/a\>/g' _build/html/downloadPDF.html
        @echo "Done adding PDF to HTML"
        @echo "Removing LaTeX dir"
        rm -rf _build/latex
        @echo "Done removing LaTeX dir"

        $(SPHINXBUILD) -b html $(ALLSPHINXOPTS) $(BUILDDIR)/html
        @echo
        @echo "Build finished. The HTML pages are in $(BUILDDIR)/html."
```

This makefile target, though a little heavier has the advantage that it's fire-and-forget; I just have to `make html` and all the documentation is done in one go and I don't have to edit any files when `make` is done. This leaves less room for me to forget to edit some file or other to make the documentation correctly before uploading to PyPI

Answer (score 2):

You could modify the `Makefile` that Sphinx placed in your `doc/build/` directory. At the end of the `latexpdf` target, add a line to copy the PDF to the html build dir. Here's an example (I only added the last line):

```
latexpdf:
    $(SPHINXBUILD) -b latex $(ALLSPHINXOPTS) $(BUILDDIR)/latex
    @echo "Running LaTeX files through pdflatex..."
    $(MAKE) -C $(BUILDDIR)/latex all-pdf
    @echo "pdflatex finished; the PDF files are in $(BUILDDIR)/latex."
    cp $(BUILDDIR)/latex/*pdf $(BUILDDIR)/html/
```

You can then add a link to the PDF in your `README.rst`.

(If the README is included in your Sphinx, this probably gives you a Sphinx warning, though, for a missing target file. Unless you also copy the PDF to your source dir. But then you have the risk of an older version being copied.)

My suggestion: add a "raw html" entry to your `README.rst`, it also has the advantage of not showing up in the PDF output :-)

```
.. raw:: html

    <a href="pypi/link/to/pdf">PDF version</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative (also to my other answer) is to let http://readthedocs.org build and host your documentation. They can also build PDFs, so you can provide a link to the PDF (build and hosted by readthedocs) in your documentation and/or your `README.rst`.

For an example, look at https://readthedocs.org/projects/zestreleaser/downloads/. You see links there for a PDF, an epub and a zipped html download. Could be exactly what you want.